# WEBSERVICE ASP.NET Método não encontrado

Tags: asp.net, web-service, vb.net, wsdl, asmx

To com um problema em um webservice que criei e já tentei várias opções de ajuste e não consegui resolver.

Tenho a lista de Métodos disponiveis conforme a imagem abaixo

[image: Listagem dos Métodos disponíveis]

Quando seleciono o método VAPS o formulário para preenchimento dos campos aparece corretamente e se preencho e envio funciona corretamente.

[image: Chamada do Método]

A url que deve ser construída para ser invocada por GET deve possuir o seguinte formato conforme a documentação.

[image: Modelo de chamada do Método]

Porém ao executar essa url recebo a seguinte mensagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Todos os outros métodos estão funcionais, o problema de método não encontrado ocorre somente com esse que é uma nova implementação, acredito que tenha algo no projeto que não foi atualizado.

Alguém já passou por isso e teria uma solução?

Já reiniciei Maquina, ISS, Visual Studio, alterei parâmetros de entrada, tipo de retorno e nada disso funcionou.

```
<WebMethod()>
    Public Function VAPS(CodTransacao As String, Email As String, Cod_Prod As Integer) As Boolean
        Dim cn As New MySqlConnection
        Dim sql As String

        Try
            sql = "SELECT * FROM TBL_CONCLUDED WHERE COD_PROD=@CodProd AND COD_TRANS=@CodTrans AND email=@email"

            Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodProd", Cod_Prod)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodTrans", CodTransacao)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Email)

            cn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("StrConn")

            Dim DA As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dt As New Data.DataTable

            cn.Open()

            DA.Fill(dt)

            MsgBox(dt.Rows.Count)

            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            'MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            Return False
        End Try

        cn.Close()

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde.

Fica difícil opinar sem ver o código, mas a primeira coisa que eu faria é forçar um [HTTPGet] no seu web metódo. Exemplo:

```
[HTTPGet]
public string VAPS()
{
   ...
}
```

Já tentou fazer isso?

Comment: Diretamente não, vou tentar aqui. Mas estou colocando no WebConfig o seguinte:
<protocols>
          <add name="HttpSoap"/>
          <add name="HttpPost"/>
          <add name="HttpGet"/>
          <!--<remove name="Documentation"/>-->
        </protocols>

O Estranho é os outros métodos funcionarem

Comment: Depois de tentar, informa aqui se funcionou ou não. Abraço.

Comment: Não funciona, o erro persiste como Método não encontrado porém a descrição continua correta.Pra mim não faz sentido nenhum os outros funcionarem e somente esse novo método não.

Comment: Eu acho que pode ser a forma de acessar o método. Você está tentando acessar o método via GET, mas pode ser que ele esteja configurado para POST. Já tentou acessá-lo via POST?

Comment: via post é a segunda imagem e por lá ela funciona.. Por isso não considero que o código esteja errado se estivesse quando eu invocasse o metodo teria um erro...Esse é o resultado do processamento <boolean xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">false</boolean>

Comment: HUM.. tem como postar o código?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com o código

Comment: Cara achei o erro na chamada eu estava usando uma ? ao invés de /. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Disponha. Abraço.